# Iterate through a json file in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json file like this :

```
[
{
    "Teacher Code": "1",
    "Teacher Name": "Papadopoulos",
    "MaxHoursPerDay":5,
    "MaxHoursPerWeek":18,
    "Teacher Lessons": [
        "Fysikh Agwgh"
    ]
},
{
    "Teacher Code": "2",
    "Teacher Name": "Nikolaou",
    "MaxHoursPerDay":4,
    "MaxHoursPerWeek":8,
    "Teacher Lessons": [
        "Thriskeytika"
    ]
},
{
    "Teacher Code": "3",
    "Teacher Name": "Anastasopoulou",
    "MaxHoursPerDay":4,
    "MaxHoursPerWeek":18,
    "Teacher Lessons": [
        "Ksenh Glwssa 1"
    ]
}...
```

and I want to iterate through that file and create java objects using jackson objectMapper and store those items in an arrayList.Here is what I have tried:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("Teachers.txt");
ArrayList<Teacher> tList = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Teacher>>(){};
```

But is shows me the error: type TypeReference does not take parameters.
 Whats the best way to do this without knowing the length of the json file?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and then let us know how your attempt is not working well for you.

Comment: Use a List<Teacher> object as the top class.

Comment: I have edited the question